# Flexbox: collapse 2 columns to single column on mobile but rearrange elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am struggling with understanding the full flexibility of flexbox (pun intended) for my product page. I have my desktop setup as follows: There is two column divs in the flex container. The left column has a single div in it which contains the product image (Call DIV 1). The right column div has two divs in it , the title/description div (call DIV 2) and a variation swatch (size and colors inputs) div (call DIV3). For mobile I wanted a single column which I am able to achieve with flex-direction:column but the ordering is what I want to adjust. Basically the left column is on top then the right column is under such that the ordering is DIV 1 , DIV2, and DIV3. However, I want to split up DIV2 and DIV3 such that the order is DIV2, DIV1 , and then DIV3.

My current solution I cannot tell if its good practice or not but I have created a second version of DIV2 and put in the left column and I hide until mobile kicks in and I make it visible and then hide the right column version of DIV2.

I would like to know if flexbox can be a full solution for this and also I want to know if my hiding and unhiding duplicate elements for mobile and desktop is poor practice as it was my only solution I could think of when using flexbox. My site implementation of this can be seen at [www.printperry.com/home/product-page/index.php](http://www.printperry.com/home/product-page/index.php)

Comment: Hey Shaun, If you can show us some code it would be easier. If you could throw it in a codepen we can take a closer look at what you're currently doing and help you modify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You kind of have hit a limit on what flexbox can do for you here, and while you can re-arrange things using `order` on each flex item it's not going to help you much as the stuff (product info) you want to reorder on mobile are nested inside another div for the purpose of displaying stacked next to a photo on desktop view. In this case it is more appropriate to look into using `display:grid`.
You can set it up for desktop as 2 columns and 3 rows, and have the image div span 3 rows. Then change the layout again for the mobile view, see below;

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  display: grid;
  /*set up a grid layout, 2 by 3 */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3 1fr);
}

.product-images {
/* make image div span all 3 rows starting from the 1st */
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}


/*mobile styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  .container {
  /*single column layout*/
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  
  .product-description {
  /*move prod description to first row of grid*/
    grid-row-start: 1;
  }
  
  .product-images {
   /*move images to second row, everything else follows under neath*/
    grid-row-start: 2;
  }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product-images">
    [Product Image Set here]
  </div>
  <div class="product-description">
    <span>T-Shirts</span>
    <h1>Gildan 2000</h1>
    <p>Purchase your products blank at wholesale or even better choose your color and sizes and click customize. Use our free online designer to make your designs come to life!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="product-configuration">
    [Product Configuration controls here]
  </div>
  <div class="product-price">
    <span>148$</span>
    <a href="#" class="cart-btn">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot. I have read about grids but never used them.This solution will be good to study from. Is grids highly supported on all modern browsers?

Comment: Yes modern browsers support them from 2017 on, except as usual internet explorer > https://caniuse.com/?search=grid